# What should I put in the for attribute of the label tag

Tags: html

What should I put in the `for` attribute of the `label` tag?

I thought that it should be ID of the element I want to bind with this `label` but it seems that many people uses `name` instead.

Who's right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MDN you should use it for the `ID`:

> The ID of a labelable form-related element in the same document as the label element. The first such element in the document with an ID matching the value of the for attribute is the labeled control for this label element.

Source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 1):

> name

as used on the form controls (input, textarea, select, button elements) is radically different from the id attribute on named elements. In this case, the name attribute relates to how data is labeled when sent to server, and multiple elements may share the same name. The

> id

attribute on the other hand is for identifying one unique element for the purposes of scripting, styling, or addressing
***ID and for value will be same.***